# Next step up from raspberry pi?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, linux-server

I'm looking for a home server in a mini-desktop form factor. I was looking at raspberry pi but it's too slow. I've been eyeing the mac-mini but it's too expensive. As far as linux based OSs any other ideas for a tiny server?

Comment: As is written in the answer, if you know WHAT to serve and you really have to serve, you will know what kind of a machine you want and then the price not necessarily will be your concern. Until then, you can use any kind of a second-hand desktop/laptop to play with. Or NAS if you mean file server by "server", it's not clear yet.

Comment: A HP Microserver could be a good bet, although its small rather than tiny. With the cashback offers they are ridiculously cheap.

Answer (score 2):

Lots of options, depending on your price / performance tradeoff curve.

An [Intel NUC](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/nuc/overview.html) or equivalent may be a good idea.
For something less powerful the [Edison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Edison). 
Less powerful again, the [Beagleboard](http://beagleboard.org/bone) or [cubieboard](http://cubieboard.org/)

There are plenty others as well.

[Here](http://ps://www.sparkfun.com/news/1688) is a comparison between the Pi, Beagleboard and Edison.

Comment: Don't forget, hardware recommendations are off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use a [Intel® Compute Stick](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/compute-stick/intel-compute-stick.html)
than again, I don't know what your budget is or your demands are. As for Linux, you can install Linux on this Intel stick or buy one with all-ready installed.